# Does Varnish support unix domain socket files?

Tags: linux, nginx, varnish, socket, posix

Does varnish support unix socket files?

I'd like to accelerate my website by adding a varnish reverse proxy (HTTP accelerator/cache) before my web server. My web server's virtual host is currently configured to listen for connections on a "UNIX-domain socket". For more info on this config, see the "`path`" argument for the "`listen`" directive in NGINX:

- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen

Is it possible for varnish to communicate to my existing nginx server's config over a unix domain socket file as its backend?

And is it possible for varnish to also *itself* listen on a domain socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish has had support for Unix Domain Sockets (UDS) for both [clients](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/upgrading-6.0.html#upd-6-0-uds-acceptor) and [backend servers](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/upgrading-6.0.html#upd-6-0-uds-backend) since [Varnish 6.0](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/changes-6.0.html?highlight=socket) was released in [March 2018](https://varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-announce/2018-March/000726.html).

You can define a backend to use a UDS using the [`.path` field](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/whats-new/upgrading-6.0.html#unix-domain-sockets-as-backend-addresses) in the `backend` declaration. Or by using the [`-b` argument](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnishd.html#ref-varnishd-options) in `varnishd`.

Varnish itself can listen on a UDS using the [`-a` argument](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnishd.html#ref-varnishd-options) when starting `varnishd`